# Can I safely hook up an outlet to this light switch?

Tags: electrical, wiring, receptacle

I want to add just one outlet to charge our Dyson vacuum in the pantry.

The light switch only turns on the light. Is it safe to run a cable down to an outlet?

[image]

Comment: Without detaching any wires or removing any wire nuts, can you pull the bundles of wires (with their wire nuts) out so we can see what each one has?

Comment: ...and with the breaker turned off, of course ;^)

Comment: you could add a consumer-level bulb-to-outlet+bulb+pullstring-switch  "tee" and not re-wire anything, if that's all you needed

Answer (score 4):

It appears that you have a neutral as well as hot and switched hot in the box, though the exact arrangement is not quite clear in the picture, so you should be able to power an un-switched receptacle from this location.

Depending on exactly what you have for wires in the box and the size of this box, you MAY need a larger box to add 2 more wires (and a ground, but the ground is probably free from what can be seen here) due to "box fill calculations" or you may not if the box is large enough.

It looks like (but remains a bit unclear, partly hidden) you have power in, power out, and switched power out on 3 different cables, so you have 6 wires, 3 grounds (count as 1 wire up to 4), a pigtail that's free and two counts for the switch (device yoke.)

So, 9 - which needs 18 cubic inches for 14AWG at 2.0 cubic inches per wire count, or 20.25 cubic inches for 12 AWG at 2.25 cubic inches per wire count.

Two more wires and a ground (which is free if it's the 4th) add 4 or 4.5 cubic inches to the required miniumum box size for 14 or 12 AWG. If the circuit has a 20A breaker all wires must be at least 12AWG; if the circuit has a 15A breaker they can be 14 AWG (which is *smaller* than 12 AWG if your'e unfamiliar with how wire gauge works.)